P va NP regarding
I have discovered a deterministic polynomial time algorithm for generalized n^2 x n^2 Sudoku puzzle, my program can solve any given valid Sudoku puzzle in steps by reasoning almost like a man. The problem is declared to be of type NP-COMPLETE. I've used the above algorithm and developed a computer program which can solve Max-Clique problem too. I think the said work proves P=NP!
Can you guide me what shall I do next?
My direct contact number is [removed]
If I talk anyone they are asking me to send the work for study and verification.
